# Display data from variables with condition

Tags: php, variables

I've a question for you if you can help me, I've some variables that I retrieve with them data from database, but I want to resolve this problem 
`if all the variables are empty then show something if not then show the just the variables that have data`.

The Code is:

```
foreach ($row as $result) {
    if ($row[29] == '') {
        $string29 = '';
    }else if ($row[29] == 0){
        $string29 = '';
    } else{
        $string29 = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Pression</h1><img src="images/'.$row[29].'.png"></div>';
    }
}

foreach ($row as $result) {
    if ($row[30] == '') {
        $string30 = '';
    }else if($row[30] == 0){
        $string30 = '';
    } else{
        $string30 = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Fixation</h1><img src="images/'.$row[30].'.png"></div>';
    }
}
```

`

Then I have 
`echo &string29 and so on........`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is rather redundant. By PHP typecasting rules, `0` and `''` are actually loosely equal:

```
php > var_dump(0 == '');
bool(true)
```

What you should be doing is have an array of keys/names you could loop over, e.g:

```
$fields = array(29 => 'Pression', 30 => 'Fixation');

foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
   if ($row[$key]) { .... }
   echo '...';
}
```

Comment: Can you be more Detailed please?